# The Spectrum Database isn't working for me error [500]

Tags: .net, database, windows-phone-8, spectrum

The error is "Internal Database Error" [500]. I made a windows phone 8 application that uses the .NET version of the Google Spectrum Database API. All my code is the way its supposed to be I just get this error. I can't even use the "Explore this API" feature from the Google Console in the browser because it says "Please activate this API for your project" and of course I have it activated.

Comment: This sounds like you did not activate the API properly for some reason. But this is hard to tell without some more information.

Comment: I went to the APIs section of the Developers Console and turned the "Google Spectrum Database API" to ON. Is there another way?